# Aligning/indenting function parameters in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, indentation, code-formatting

In Netbeans PHP, I want the next parameter to line up with the start of the first one on the previous line, but auto-indenting only gives me the following format:

```
my_function( $a,
        $b,
        ... );
```

What I want is:

```
my_function( $a,
             $b,
             ... );
```

Can Netbeans be set to do this?  All I have seen so far is the ability to set a fixed number of spaces to be indented on parameter continuation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't write PHP in Netbeans, but for Java you can do `Options > Editor > Formatting > Java > Alignment > check Method Parameters` to get the effect you want when you do a `Source > Format`. I imagine you can do something similar for the PHP editor.

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans 8.2 it is available at Options > Editor > Formatting:
Language: php -
Category: wrapping -
Method Parameters: Always -
(Method call Arguments: always)